# \nobreak not working after multicol

Tags: page-breaking, multicol

Let's say I want to have a horizontal line at the end of every section, but it can't be isolated after a page break.

Here's a minimal example:

```latex
\usepackage{latexbug}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=15cm, paperheight=20cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\widowpenalties 4 9999 9000 6000 2000
\clubpenalties 4 9999 9000 6000 2000

\newcommand{\formattedsection}[2]{
    \section{#1}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        #2
    \end{multicols}
    \par
    \nobreak\hrulefill  % SHOULD BE ON THE SAME PAGE
}

\begin{document}

\formattedsection{My Section}{\lipsum[1-2]}

\end{document}

\begin{document}

\formattedsection{My Section}{\lipsum[1-2]}

\end{document}
```

And here is what I get:

[image]

The horizontal line is in an isolated page, as I didn't want.

I did many tests and the problem seems to be multicol. I'm guessing it already defines that the end of multicols is a good place for a page break. Is there a way to revert that?

If I remove multicol, and since I defined widow penalties, the last lines of the text get moved to the next page in case the rule doesn't fit the page (image below). I believe this would be the expected behavior for columns too.

[image]

Comment: It is somewhat more complicated than that. At the end of multicol, it checks whether there is enough room to insert some vertical space and continue outputting stuff. If not multicol will force a page break. This is probably what happened in your case.

Comment: I tried to edit the code in `multicol.sty` and remove all the `\newpage` commands, but it made no difference.

Comment: That won't work. Even if you remove the enforced page break, there's still the possibility that there is simply not enough room left on the page for the rule. You need to also change the output routine for multicol so that instead of ending the multicol at the bottom of a page with no space left, it instead makes the page underfull and flow some text to the next page, so that there will be enough room for the rule. // The output routine is quite complicated (takes up 10 pages in the multicol documentation).

Comment: Instead of looking for an automatic way, I would instead, on a case-by-case basis when such edge cases are encountered, use `\enlargethispage` to force some extra room at the bottom of the page and reset the length `\postmulticols` to something tiny, so that multicol will not put in a new page and you will have made room for the rule. The caveat is that if you have two pages open you will likely be able to see that one page is "longer".